# Can't Find Locally Installed Module in Windows

Tags: node.js, npm

I've got a very simple script that I'm using to test this scenario, but I can't figure out why Node wouldn't be able load the module that's locally installed.

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "cli-progress-bar": "^0.1.0"
  }
}
```

Test.js:

```js
var ProgressBar = require("cli-progress-bar"),
    progress = new ProgressBar(),
    processed = 0;

function update () {
    if (processed < 100) {
        progress.show(++processed / 100);
        setTimeout(update, 750);
    }
}

update();
```

As far as I can tell, this should just load the `cli-progress-bar` package, and run a simple progress bar to completion before exiting.

This is the output I get when I try to install the dependencies and run the script:

```
C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop\Test>node -v
v4.2.1

C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop\Test>npm -v
3.3.10

C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop\Test>npm install
Test@1.0.0 C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop\Test
└─┬ cli-progress-bar@0.1.0
  ├── cli-character-set@0.1.0
  ├─┬ lodash.padleft@3.1.1
  │ ├── lodash._basetostring@3.0.1
  │ └─┬ lodash._createpadding@3.6.1
  │   └── lodash.repeat@3.0.1
  ├── lodash.padright@3.1.1
  └─┬ log-update@1.0.2
    ├── ansi-escapes@1.1.0
    └─┬ cli-cursor@1.0.2
      └─┬ restore-cursor@1.0.1
        ├── exit-hook@1.1.1
        └── onetime@1.0.0

npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON Test@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON Test@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON Test@1.0.0 No license field.

C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop\Test>node Test.js
module.js:339
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'cli-progress-bar'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop\Test\Test.js:1:81)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
```

I can see that the the package is installed in `C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop\Test\node_modules` but I can't seem to use it.

```
C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop\Test>dir node_modules
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 7294-620F

 Directory of C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop\Test\node_modules

11/02/2015  10:00 AM    <DIR>          .
11/02/2015  10:00 AM    <DIR>          ..
11/02/2015  10:00 AM    <DIR>          ansi-escapes
11/02/2015  10:00 AM    <DIR>          cli-character-set
11/02/2015  10:00 AM    <DIR>          cli-cursor
11/02/2015  10:00 AM    <DIR>          cli-progress-bar
11/02/2015  10:00 AM    <DIR>          exit-hook
11/02/2015  10:00 AM    <DIR>          lodash.padleft
11/02/2015  10:00 AM    <DIR>          lodash.padright
11/02/2015  10:00 AM    <DIR>          lodash.repeat
11/02/2015  10:00 AM    <DIR>          lodash._basetostring
11/02/2015  10:00 AM    <DIR>          lodash._createpadding
11/02/2015  10:00 AM    <DIR>          log-update
11/02/2015  10:00 AM    <DIR>          onetime
11/02/2015  10:00 AM    <DIR>          restore-cursor
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
              15 Dir(s)  283,532,754,944 bytes free

C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop\Test>npm ls
Test@1.0.0 C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop\Test
└─┬ cli-progress-bar@0.1.0
  ├── cli-character-set@0.1.0
  ├─┬ lodash.padleft@3.1.1
  │ ├── lodash._basetostring@3.0.1
  │ └─┬ lodash._createpadding@3.6.1
  │   └── lodash.repeat@3.0.1
  ├── lodash.padright@3.1.1
  └─┬ log-update@1.0.2
    ├── ansi-escapes@1.1.0
    └─┬ cli-cursor@1.0.2
      └─┬ restore-cursor@1.0.1
        ├── exit-hook@1.1.1
        └── onetime@1.0.0
```

Every time I try to run the script, I get the same error.

Comment: I've searched for other people having this issue, but I can only find questions from people having trouble loading *globally* installed modules. This is definitely installed locally.

Comment: I'm not sure where to start on this one. If everyone decides that it's a problem to this specific package, I'll open an issue in its Github repository.

Comment: So there are no node_modules folder in the directory your test script is in?

Comment: @simon-p-r, I can see that it is installed in that folder's `node_modules`. `npm ls` seems to confirm that as well.

Comment: And the node_modules folder has a folder called cli-progress-bar inside it?  Very strange

Comment: @simon-p-r, yes. I've added that info to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why you cannot find module called "cli-progress-bar" is because that module is not exposing itself correctly.  The package.json file has a property called main which must be set to the name of script being exported from module.  If script is called index.js npm will find it however because script is called bar.js and the package.json file is saying the main file is called index.js it is not being exposed properly and cannot be found by require.

Comment: Wow, good catch. Thank you! I'll open an issue for that package then.

Comment: No problem I have made a PR [here](https://github.com/gillesdemey/cli-progress-bar/pull/2) to fix issue